# Groovy DSL - shortcut for creating objects

Tags: groovy, dsl

is there a way in Groovy to replace some code like the below:

```
Task a = new Task('a')
Process p = new Process('p')
```

with something easier, like:

```
task a
process p
```

where `task` and `process` can be method calls that create the object and return it or add it to the script Map.

The main problem I currently have is that I cannot use `a` because it is not defined.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create objects and name them without assigning to a variable, you can use a binding.  Create and keep a reference to the a closure's binding, and have the utility methods `task` and `process` associate the new instance with the name.  For example:

```
def scriptBinding = new Binding()

def task = { String name ->
    scriptBinding[name] = new Task(name)
}
def process = { String name ->
    scriptBinding[name] = new Process(name)
}

def script = {
    task 'a'
    process 'b'

    println a
    println b
}
script.binding = scriptBinding
script()
```

Note that you have to quote `a` and `b` so they are interpreted as strings instead of undefined variables.  If you'd like to omit quotes, you can use a custom Binding object that evaluates undefined symbols as their string representation like this:

```
class SymbolAsStringBinding extends Binding {
    Object getVariable(String name) {
        try {
            super.getVariable(name)
        } catch (MissingPropertyException e) {
            name
        }
    }

    boolean hasVariable(String name) {
        true
    }
}
```

With that addition, you can write the script as:

```
def script = {
    task a
    process b

    println a
    println b
}
```

Comment: You can also use `def propertyMissing(String p) { p }` to avoid a custom binding and already have the variable resolving to a string

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
class Task {
    String name
    Task(name) { this.name = name }
    String toString() { "task: $name".toString() }
}

def propertyMissing(String name) { this.getBinding()[name] = name }

def task(name) { this.getBinding()[name]  = new Task(name) }

task a
println a
```

this will produce:

```
 task: a
```

essentially when you reach the

```
task a
```

statement the `propertyMissing()` will put in the binding a variable named `a` with content it's name.
Later the `task()` function will replace the variable `a` in the binding with the new Task passing as name the name of the missing varible `a`